# Unity 11.10 and VGA output to flat screen TV

Tags: unity, display

When I connect a VGA cable from my HP laptop to my SONY 40" flat screen, I get a weird looking desktop: it tends to have everything on the right but no dash, icons etc.

I enabled CCSM and checked different multiple desktop views there and found each desktop is doubled width-wise and only display the right hand desktop (no icons and no AWN dock - they are only on the left hand desktop).
Also, I can right click and choose Change Desktop Background, then All Settings to get to System Settings. In displays, it shows the laptop and the TV is shown as 72" Sony.

I've tried all the resolutions for the TV display but everything gives me what I've described above. The resolution on the laptop in Windows is 1024x768 60 htz -- this would be a great option in 11.10 but is not available.

Any ideas on how I can change the Displays to show a 40" Sony? Or at least create a resolution that will show each desktop, without the schism?

Answer (score 1):

Sharing a screen with TV's on Ubuntu has always proven to be a bit problematic with me. Most LCD/LED TVs tend to have a `auto-detect` or `auto-adapt` setting built into the Menu GUI or remote, this is where I recommend you start. If you do not have any luck with this; I would suggest that you attempt to increase the resolution. For a 40" screen television, the native resolution is certainly going to be something closer to **1920 x 1080** pixels; most HD televisions are like this. If you change your television to the primary monitor you will find you have many more resolution options in the **16:9** display ratio.

If you go and run the program Displays, you will see a screen very familiar to Windows; here you can enable and disable you native screen, screen sharing, desktop resolution, and set mirror displays. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found I could click and re-order the displays. so I could put the Sony on the left and laptop to the right. Then, I turned off the laptop and got a decent output to the Sony. Using wireless k/m, I achieved what I believe was a 1920 x 1280 << very awesome!!!

Then came the flash update that screwed up my browser: after fixing that, I tried the big screen again.

Now if I connect the VGA cable, I get no laptop display and Sony is all garbled and unviewable!

Does anyone know where my display preference file is located? If I could get rid of that, I think I could start from scratch and get back to what I was trying to do in the first place!